# Silverstripe merge GroupedLists

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm trying to return a single `GroupedList` which holds information from both pages and `dataobjects`. Is there an easy way to merge the two lists together?

```
public function getGroupedContent()
{
    $dataobjects = GroupedList::create(FileNetObject::get());
    $pages = GroupedList::create($this->Children());

    $result = ??;


    return $result;
}
```

The `ArrayList` merge fails as does a standard `array_merge` - Would I be best merging the results from the queries together before putting it into a single `GroupedList`?

Comment: do FileNetObject and $this->Children() have anything in common? both are pages? or can you group them by some common fields or getters?

Comment: @wmk both contain title fields which I'm using to group on.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your situation, the simplest way to do this is:

```
return array_merge($dataobjects->toArray(), $pages->toArray());
```

To display the above in a template you would of course need to wrap that in another ArrayList.

Updated: If you want to group the lists (which of course is why you were using a GroupedList in the first place) you would need to do it before merging the arrays. More like:

```
return array_merge($dataobjects->GroupBy('Author')->toArray(), $page->GroupBy('Author')->toArray());
```

Comment: Following above, and then placing the results of the array_merge into another ArrayList, would I need to modify the template to anything other than looping the children of the groupedlist? (currently renders nothing)

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed your comment. Without seeing your template it's hard to say. If you still have $GroupBy in your template you would want to remove that bit. Otherwise if you post your code I can try to look further.